# Hello i just want to add loged in user id to my apple table everthing works fine but user_id table did not get user id

Tags: php, database, laravel, postman

```
public function applee(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
       
    ]);
    $apple = new Apple;
    $apple->user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $apple-> transaction_id =  $request->transaction_id;
    $apple->buyer_name =  $request->buyer_name;
    $apple-> address =  $request->address;
    $apple->  phone =  $request->phone;
    $apple-> email =  $request->email;

    $apple-> city =  $request->city;
    $apple-> payment_method =  $request->payment_method;
    $apple->   plan_id =  $request->plan_id;
    $apple-> selected_products_ids =  $request->selected_products_ids;
    $apple->   plan_purchase_date = $request->plan_purchase_date;


    $apple->content = $request->content;

    $apple->save();
    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
    ], 201);
}
```

Hello i just want to add loged in user id to my apple table everthing works fine but user_id table did not get the user id in db table apple although i was testing this on postman by passing header bearer token

Comment: Does your Apple model happen to have a property named `user_id` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Do a **Auth::check()** before processing :

```
public function applee(Request $request) 
{ 
   $request->validate([
       //
    ]); 

     if(Auth::check() {
       $apple = new Apple;
       $apple->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
       $apple->transaction_id =  $request->transaction_id;
       $apple->buyer_name =  $request->buyer_name;
       $apple->address =  $request->address;
       $apple->phone =  $request->phone;
       $apple->email =  $request->email;

       $apple-> city =  $request->city;
       $apple-> payment_method =  $request->payment_method;
       $apple->plan_id =  $request->plan_id;
       $apple->selected_products_ids =  $request->selected_products_ids;
       $apple->plan_purchase_date = $request->plan_purchase_date;

       $apple->content = $request->content;

       $apple->save();
       return response()->json([
           'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
       ], 201);
    } else {
       return response()->json([
           'message' => 'You are not logged in!'
       ], 201);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i add in fillable butt after this each user id gets 0 id number

Comment: Aru you using `auth:api`? ,  try with `$user_id = $request->user()->id;`

Comment: Aru you using `auth:api`? , try with `$user_id = $request->user()->id;` or  `auth()->user()-id;`

Comment: `auth('api')->user()` returns the authenticated user (or null if the user is not logged on) - even if middleware is not used.  Use this `$apple->user_id = auth('api')->user();`  if it helps then let me know. I l'll edit my answer.

Comment: $apple->user_id = auth('api')->user();  this still return empty i am using token in postman

Comment: Hope this can help you a bit https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-passport-unauthorized-postman?page=1

Comment: NOPE i still got emplty